# Wampserver RewriteRule issue

Tags: php

I want to enter localhost/expl/admin/add-edit-category/ and have it process localhost/expl/admin/add-edit-category.php

The following .htaccess **works fine on two different production servers**, but results in a 404 on localhost (Wampserver 3.1.3, Apache 2.4.33, PHP 7.1.16)

```
RewriteBase /expl/
RewriteRule     ^admin/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$   /expl/admin/$1\.php    [QSA,NC,L]
```

However, if I do something like this, it's fine on Wampserver:

Enter: localhost/expl/dummy-dir/admin/add-edit-category/

```
RewriteRule     ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/admin/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$   /expl/admin/$2\.php?dir=$1    [QSA,NC,L]
```

It will read the variables just fine and everything works as expected. So why is the first case falling over?

Another related issue (which is resulting in "too many redirect" errors) is localhost already allows entering URIs without file extensions, so e.g. localhost/expl/admin/add-edit-category in the address bar processes localhost/expl/admin/add-edit-category.php, but I don't want it to do so (it's not how it works on the production servers and I need it to be consistent on my local machine). I can't find any settings in Wampserver that cause this, so I can remove it.

Comment: For the last part - disable the `MultiViews` option. For all the rest – enable rewrite logging, and find out what is actually going on.

Comment: Disabling Multiviews fixed both issues. Thank you!